# Cannot get setTextSpacing of PagerTabStrip to work

Tags: java, android, user-interface, viewpagerindicator

I am trying to reduce the gap between titles in the pager tab strip, so that they're closer to each other, instead of one being in the end of the strip.

According to the docs, setTextSpacing(int textSpacing) should work, but it dosn't.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should try this library then: https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip